# .Net MVC Core Modular Project Structure and Managing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

As company, we want to deploy our .net desktop project to MVC Core web application.  We have 30 different modules and one of them is developed by different developers. Also one module can be used in another module. How can we achieve it in terms of project structure in Visual Studio? We don't want to build one project including all of modules. Each module will be delivered to different solution for different developer in our company. Basic menu and modules structures is as below:

```
Main Project : TicariEntegreMenu.WebUI.dll   (AnaMenu)
1) Login
2) Session Info
3) Menu / Modules
 1. Stok Module                      (Stok.WebUI)
    1.1 İşlemler 
        1.1.1 Stok Kartı Tanıtımı    (Stok.WebUI.Controller.Stok.StokKarti)
        1.1.2 Stok Fiyat Güncelleme  (Stok.WebUI.Controller.Stok.FiyatGuncelle) 
        1.1.3 Depo Girişi               
        1.1.4 Depo Çıkısı           
    1.2 Raporlar
        1.2.1 Stok Kartı Raporu
        1.2.2 Stok Envanter Raporu
 2. Fatura Modülü                     (Fatura.WebUI)
    2.1 İşlemler
        2.1.1 Alış Faturası           (Fatura.WebUI.Controller.Fatura.Alis)
        2.2.2 Satış Faturası          (Fatura.WebUI.Controller.Fatura.Satis)
    2.2 Raporlar
        ....
        ....
        ...

  Stok.WebUI bir proje         Stok.WebUI.dll / Stok.WebUI.Views.dll
  Fatura.WebUI bir proje       Fatura.WebUI.dll /  Fatura.WebUI.Views.dll
```

Comment: "one module can be used in another module" - interfaces in a third shared module and dependency injection can help with that, depending on the specifics.

Comment: You can still create a single solution file with segmented over multiple class libraries. If you really need to separate solution for different developers, then deploy them as nuget packages, and other developers can import them in their project. But line by line debugging will get hit by that.

Comment: Good approach for me. But can you give an example or link for this? Thanks for useful answer. @Teomanshipahi